# Get Objects array from Cookies

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I know how to  save some object array in cookies and get it back  using json but how  to get this array in C# code from Request.Cookies ?

```
function onAddToBasket(id, price) {
  var items = getItems()
  items.push({ ID: id, Price: price });
  $.cookie("ubasubasket", JSON.stringify(items), { path: '/' });
}

//Getting date from cookies
function getItems() {
  var items = [];
  if ($.cookie('ubasubasket') != undefined) {
      items = JSON.parse($.cookie('ubasubasket'));
  }
  return items;
}


//C# action in controller
public void Test()
{
   var r2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request.Cookies["ubasubasket"].Value);
  /*And here i get ERROR:
  {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0."} */
}
```

Comment: What is the content of "Request.Cookies["ubasubasket"].Value" before you try to deserialize it?

Comment: some hashed string that looks like usual json

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
   public void Test()
   {
       MyCookie = Request.Cookies["ubasubasket"];
       //Grab all values for single cookie into an object array.
       String[] arr2 = MyCookie.Values.AllKeys;

       //Loop through cookie Value collection and print all values.
       for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < arr2.Length; loop2++) 
       {
          Response.Write("Value" + loop2 + ": " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[loop2]) + "<br>");
       }
   }
```

Comment: Result is 'Value0:  '